# Upgrade from RN 0.60.6 to 0.61.2 throws ld: library not found for -lReact

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Before upgrading to 0.61.2 everything was compiling fine on Xcode but now, it throws

```
ld: library not found for -lReact
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Specifically to my AppTests, not the app itself.

This is my Podfile

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'MyApp' do
  # Pods for MyApp
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  # pod 'React-ART', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ART'
  # pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/jscallinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'


  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  pod 'RNImageCropPicker', :path =>  '../node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker'

  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_native_modules!
end

target 'MyApp-tvOS' do
  # Pods for MyApp

  target 'MyApp-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

And on Xcode, it throws that error but indicating it's on MyAppTests.

I'm using the **.xcworkspace** and not .xproject file. (using CocoaPods)

I followed [this guideline](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.60.6&to=0.61.2) and applied every change showing from 0.60.6 to 0.61.2.

Any idea of what could be failing here? Tried deleting DerivedData folder, cleaned and re-compiled like 5 times already but still fails in the same spot.

I even deleted the libReact.a from my /Frameworks folder. Still didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried pod deintegration or not? I did  in 3 project upgrades to 0.61 no problem

Comment: How do i run a deintegration? what does it do? I have to check how to do it.

Comment: pod deintegrate    is the command to run in your ios directory from terminal!   then run pod clean to delete the pod file!    make sure XCODE is not open!

Comment: I had to re-do it all over and it worked. Thanks!